# How set AWS Cognito App client settings via code in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to find a way to configure the equivalent options you see in the screenshot below via code, using serverless.yml.

[image: App integration settings]

I can already setup most of the infrastructure (user pool, identity pool, lambdas) using serverless.yml, but I can't find any docs for how to set those settings.

Any idea?

Thanks,